# Как сделать, чтобы приложение работало в фоновом режиме на flutter?

Tags: flutter

создаю приложение экрана блокировки на flutter для ios и android, хочу чтобы приложение работало в фоне, т.е. при включении экрана телефона "вылазило" окно ввода пин-кода моего приложения, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать пакет [fgbg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fgbg). Он позволяет отслеживать, когда приложение "засыпает" и "просыпается" в том числе и после блокировки экрана. Поставьте листенер на соответствующее событие и вызывайте окно ввода пин-кода.

На мой взгляд, это оптимальное решение вашего вопроса.